# PhraseQuery: can Lucene skip words from Query (not exact search) if nothing found

Tags: lucene

Suppose I'm making request `[hibernate-search] lucene phrase`. The are 2 docs that satisfy exact phrase, but there are a lot of docs with `[hibernate-search] lucene`. How should I construct a query to display exact docs first and then docs without single word (`[hibernate-search] phrase`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just OR them: `"my phrase" my phrase`.

Comment: What about sorting of results? I need docs for `"my phrase"` to be first

Comment: It will be, since it matches both the phrase and the term queries. If you're concerned, you can boost it even more: `"my phrase"^2 my phrase`.